# stable_baselines3 PPO won't learn

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I've written code for moving a target object towards a specific goal position on a 2D surface. However, when I run it, the cart doesn't move towards the object or the goal position at all. It just gets stuck in a loop and so the program never terminates. I feel this may be down to a fundamental misunderstanding about how reinforcement learning works and how it should be implemented within Python. Any advice will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

```
import math
import numpy as np

import gym
from gym import spaces
from stable_baselines3 import PPO

THRESHOLD = 50
GOAL = np.random.uniform(-THRESHOLD, THRESHOLD, 2)

class CartPushEnv2D(gym.Env):

    metadata = {
        "render_modes": ["human", "rgb_array"]
    }

    def __init__(self):
        self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(8)
        self.observation_space = spaces.Box(low = -THRESHOLD, high = THRESHOLD, shape = (4,), dtype=np.float32)

    def step(self, action):
        x_c, y_c, x_o, y_o = self.observation

        if action == 0:
            x_c -= 1
            y_c -= 1
        elif action == 1:
            x_c -= 1
            y_c += 1
        elif action == 2:
            x_c += 1
            y_c -= 1
        elif action == 3:
            x_c += 1
            y_c += 1
        elif action == 4:
            x_c += 1
        elif action == 5:
            x_c -= 1
        elif action == 6:
            y_c += 1
        else:
            y_c -= 1
        
        if np.linalg.norm(np.array([x_c, y_c]) - np.array([x_o,y_o])) <= math.sqrt(2):
            
            if action == 0:
                x_o -= 1
                y_o -= 1
            elif action == 1:
                x_o -= 1
                y_o += 1
            elif action == 2:
                x_o += 1
                y_o -= 1
            elif action == 3:
                x_o += 1
                y_o += 1
            elif action == 4:
                x_o += 1
            elif action == 5:
                x_o -= 1
            elif action == 6:
                y_o += 1
            elif action == 7:
                y_o -= 1

        self.observation = x_c, y_c, x_o, y_o

        done = bool(np.linalg.norm([x_o,y_o] - GOAL) <= math.sqrt(2))

        if bool(any(self.observation) >= THRESHOLD):
            reward = - 10*THRESHOLD
        else:
            reward = - (np.linalg.norm([x_o,y_o] - GOAL)) - (np.linalg.norm([x_c-x_o,y_c-y_o]))
        
        info = {}
        return np.array(self.observation).astype(np.float32), reward, done, info

    def reset(self):
        self.observation = np.random.uniform(-THRESHOLD, THRESHOLD, (4,))

        return np.array(self.observation).astype(np.float32)

done = False
counter = 0

env = CartPushEnv2D()
model = PPO('MlpPolicy', env, verbose=1).learn(100000)
obs = env.reset()

while not done:
    action, _ = model.predict(obs)
    print(action, _)
    obs, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
    print("goal: ", GOAL, "obs: ", obs, "reward: ", reward, "done: ", done)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine and I don't think you misunderstood DRL, rather you don't see a tree behind the forest. Look at this line:

```
 if np.linalg.norm(np.array([x_c, y_c]) - np.array([x_o,y_o])) <= math.sqrt(2):
```

this line regulates an update of the second part of your state, `x_o, y_o`. Taking into account that your interval is `[-50, 50]`, the amount of points that hit this condition is extremely low. And since you sample only at the beginning in `reset` call, I'm not surprised you never hit this line in your code and therefore your second part of the state is not updated at all, which in turn puzzles your network since your state is an input layer of it -- you could clearly see it by examining a `loss` value during your training (printed in stdout), it is always around `1e6`. So you definitely need to remake your `step` method